# Question incorrectly migrated

Tags: discussion, migration

The question ["Gaussian kernel density estimation with fixed covariance (with python)"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69674/gaussian-kernel-density-estimation-with-fixed-covariance-with-python?noredirect=1) was incorrectly migrated to StackOverflow.

Can we have it restored to Cross-Validated?

Based on [this meta question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/what-standard-should-be-applied-in-deciding-whether-a-question-requires-sufficie) it does not appear as though the original post exhibited the negative criteria listed in the highest-voted answer:

- The question includes tags for things besides a programming language.
- The question could be easily re-stated in English (with no computer code) since the idea that there is just a simple programming option to enable a full covariance-like bandwidth parameter to KDE is not a coherent criticism (there is no such simple programming option and it would involve novel research to create one.)
- The question is not *purely* mathematical, since it is about data-driven or otherwise covariance based choices in modeling data with KDE process and presumably applies to actual data given the programming references.

Along these lines, from the meta-question I linked above we have:

> "Something to notice about most of these examples is that their titles contain technical statistical terms. The presence of such words does not imply the question itself is on topic!"

I am curious if there is community support for the analagous claim: "The presence of programming-language-specific words, tags, or phrases in the title of a question does not imply the question itself is off topic!"

The question does involve a programming language, but as I interpret it, the question asks about a method to employ a more "covariance-like" notion of bandwidth within the Kernel Density Estimation framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I voted to migrate this question after some thought and reviewing the comments; this was not a clear or automatic case.  I ultimately relied on the original text to make the decision for me: it explicitly asks for a Python solution and the OP takes pains to intimate that he could program the algorithm himself, but wishes to avoid it.  That was a sufficiently clear indication that this is a pure programming question and leaves me comfortable with the decision. At this point it's out of our hands: you would need to appeal to the SO mods either to reject the migration or migrate the question back here. You ought to wait for clarification from the OP first.

Comment: This is a good point. I had not considered the point where the OP mentioned being able to program it but wished to avoid it.

Answer (score 6):

I also voted to migrate that question.  My criterion is simple:  What does the OP need explained?  If it's a statistical concept, then the thread belongs here; if it's something about how to use software, then it belongs elsewhere.  The OP asked how to fix the covariance of a Gaussian kernel to some pre-specified value in Python.  A perfectly satisfactory answer could have been:

> Yes, that's easy to do.  You set `argument=value`.

Comment: (+1) I also voted to migrate the question using similar logic.

Comment: I appreciate this perspective, but I'm of the opinion that an answer along the lines of "Yes, that's easy to do. You set argument=value." would specifically *not* be a useful or adequate answer to the question. But I agree the OP seems confused about that (based on whuber's observation above) and so based on the OP's intention, I suppose migrating it is fine.