# Internet Support for Statistics Software

Tags: discussion, faq, software

A [discussion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/400/919) in fall 2010 considered the extent to which purely software-related questions would be welcome on this site.  It didn't really reach a conclusion, but one useful suggestion that arose is to **collect a set of links to online support resources** (such as user groups and list servers) for the various statistical computing platforms.  I guess that would let us close some of these questions in a constructive and relatively guilt-free manner.  I, for one, would like to help the people who come by with questions about [SAS macro syntax](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9013/string-replace-in-sas) or  [table access](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/access-tables-created-in-sas-enterprise-guide-client-into-sas-enterprise-miner-cl), even though these questions have no direct statistical interest (and would interest only small subcommunities here) and therefore ought to be closed or migrated.

**Could we organize replies in the present thread by software platform?**  The ones of most immediate use are those that keep showing up: R, SAS, SPSS, Stata, Excel.

Comment: The (main) FAQ now links to this thread.

Answer (score 75):

## R

[R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help), and the various [R Mailing Lists or SIGs](http://www.R-project.org/mail.html), welcome any questions (provided they conform to the [Posting Guide](http://www.R-project.org/posting-guide.html)). Answers generally come within one or two days.

[Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/) gives a gentle overview of most of the basic R syntax for people coming from SAS, SPSS, or Stata. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) also provides strong support for [R questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). Additionally, [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/) provides a custom Google search that facilitates queries related to R code, packages, articles, etc. You can search the R documentation and package documentation using [rdocumentation.org](http://www.rdocumentation.org/) site. [r-universe](https://r-universe.dev/search/) features useful reviews of current packages.

The [UCLA Academic Technology Services](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/)provide [many worked examples of statistical analyses in R](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/).

If you're looking for visualization ideas, visit the [R Graph gallery](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/all-graphs/) and the [Learn R blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/), both of which feature a wide variety of plots and the accompanying code.  The [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/) page provides multiple examples and recipes for plotting data (mostly using ggplot2) plus some additional information on using R.

To add the excellent resources list above, same have found [the R Tutorial web site](http://www.r-tutor.com/) to be helpful. [R bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/) is also a helpful feed. That has lots of useful posts from various bloggers and is an excellent way to keep up with new packages and new ways of using existing packages. If you're coming from SAS or SPSS, check out [R for SAS and SPSS Users](https://r4stats.com/); there is a book with more information in it. An equivalent book for Stata users coming to R is [R for Stata Users](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computanional+statistics/book/978-1-4419-1317-3). Nice introductory tutorial can be found on [R Tutorials](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/) page – it covers introduction to basics of R, using statistical tools such as t-tests, ANOVA, regression and other topics.

There are also some resources listed on our site here: [Free resources for learning R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r), and on our [R tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info).

For learning on more advanced topics in R programming the best resource that is available online is [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) site by Hadley Wickham. It is an online version of book under the same title. Another resource covering programming issues is [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) by Patrick Burns available as pdf file. Those two cover topics that are negligible to most people that use R for statistics but can be crucial if you do actual programming in R and can be helpful in understanding how R works 'under the hood'. If trying to understand better how some R function works, you can always [check their source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) as R is open-source.

Comment: I am tolerably comfortable in R, and publishing to CRAN, but would **love** guidance on producing test functions. There's some kind of OO style specifically for test functions that I cannot seem to find documentation for and I feel so dorky publishing packages that do tests without conforming to that.

Answer (score 44):

## Python

Although this is not a statistical package *per se,* it has extensive statistical capabilities.

- [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) is a library for visualization. It has an assortment of [tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index) and a [gallery of examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/) in its documentation.
- The [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/FrontPage) is a gateway to Python.
- [Python Forum](https://www.python.org/community/forums/) is a Python-oriented Q&A site.
- From Python 3.4, [the "statistics" module](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/) will be added to the standard library.
- [Pingouin](https://pingouin-stats.org/) is a `pandas`-aware library which provides diagnostic plots, power analysis, and various statistical tests.
- [StatPy](https://pypi.org/project/statpy/) ("special emphasis on astrostatistics").
- Links to [numerical and scientific](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific) packages.
- [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for machine learning.
- [SciPy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) contains numerous classes for probability distributions and statistical tests. Other submodules of SciPy also provide numerical integration and integral transforms.
- [SemoPy2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.01140) provides trainable model classes for structural equation models. They support [exploratory](https://semopy.com/efa.html) and confirmatory approaches, [random effects](https://semopy.com/mixed.html), [latent factor scores](https://semopy.com/factor_scores.html), [mean components](https://semopy.com/means.html), among other features.
- [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html), for a variety of models including generalized linear models, Markov models, and autoregressive models. Support for [M-estimation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/robust_models_1.html), generalized least squares, maximum-likelihood, and seemingly-unrelated regression are included.
- [SymPy.stats](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html) provides a basic computer algebra system for symbolic statistical computing. The main module also provides a variety of mathematical tools such as derivatives, integrals (including Fourier transforms), and other tools that are useful in mathematical statistics.
- [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), for enhanced data structures, including time-series.

In addition, people who prefer Python for scripting, but would like access to `R`'s wide-ranging statistical capabilities can call `R` from Python with [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html#getting-started) (see also: [A Slug's Guide to Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20200412094634/https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python) (archived)).

Comment: NumPy and related questions get jumped on pretty quickly on [SO] ... As a python programmer, I can actually recommend [SO] as a default.

Comment: Tensorflow, Tensorflow Probability ( and the pytorch equivalents) for scalable probabilistic programming

Answer (score 31):

## Stata

[Statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/) is the place to go with questions about how to do things in any version of Stata.  It is very active: Stata developers from StataCorp and many experienced users are leading members. Questions cover basic Stata use, Stata programming, and statistical practice. Before posting do study the FAQ Advice [here](http://www.statalist.org/forums/help). People are asked to use their real names. As a resource with very many answered questions and for its collective expertise, Statalist is ahead of all other forums.

Questions about Stata syntax, programming and output are addressed on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata). It's best to note its aim of being a forum for professional and enthusiast programmers and its focus on specific problems with people's own code. That is, SO is not a good forum for questions that are entirely or mostly statistical, including why or how Stata commands work.

[Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/stata/) occasionally includes Stata questions. Beginner questions are common. The number of experienced users lurking there is far smaller than on Statalist and advice is variable. There is more tolerance there for students seeking advice or assistance with their assignments, a plus or minus depending on your status and your question.

Much the same applies to [Talk Stats](http://www.talkstats.com), which appears to have faded away as a  forum for Stata questions. EDIT 12 May 2023 This site now appears defunct.

Both of these last two sites allow anonymous identifiers, a plus if that is your preference.

[Stata Forum.De](http://www.stata-forum.de) is dedicated to Stata and is conducted in German. There is now little traffic.

[Quora](https://www.quora.com) supports posting of opinions about Stata and its alternatives. Specific threads based on coding seem rare at best.

There is a [Stata Users Group on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/statausersgroup/). It supports questions in Spanish as well as in English.

Stata is often mentioned on [Twitter](https://www.twitter.com) but only a few posts ask for or provide support on specific questions.

The [official FAQs](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/) are extremely useful as well. The help files for specific commands are available online; for direct access, form the url as `http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?` appended with the command name, like `regress`: http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?regress. The full pdf documentation is also available [online](http://www.stata.com/features/documentation/), e.g., the [User Guide](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u.pdf) and the [Reference](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/r.pdf) manuals are usually a good place to start for general commands.

StataCorp also maintains a [YouTube training channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/statacorp) and offers registered users free [technical support via e-mail](http://www.stata.com/support/tech-support/contact/).

ATS/UCLA has an [entire section dedicated to Stata](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/). Start from there with the [learning modules](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/modules/), the [FAQs](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/) or the "links by topic."

The StataCorp website carries information on, and a way to purchase, books on Stata: see [this page](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/books-on-stata/).

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned Stata's official command documentation, which can be found online. Normally a google search for the command will bring it up in the first few results. To narrow the search, you can add "site:www.stata.com/help.cgi" after searching for the name of the command, e.g. `regress site:www.stata.com/help.cgi`.

Comment: The pdf documentation that comes bundled with Stata is also quite excellent and well-written. Some of these manuals can even be found online. Lots of examples, formulas, and syntax. For some reason, many people seem to be unaware of their existence, even when they have used Stata for years. The link at the very top of Stata's documentation that you get when you type -help XXX- takes you there.

Comment: As from Stata 13, the entire manuals are on-line and accessible to all.

Comment: Typing -help XXX- into an internet search engine usually spits out the Stata help file as the first or second search result (at least for Google and Yahoo, anyway)

Answer (score 24):

## MATLAB

[MATLAB](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) (MATrix LABoratory) is a multi-paradigm numerical computing environment and fourth-generation programming language. It is developed by MathWorks. MATLAB has a free, open-source counterpart named [Octave](https://gnu.org/software/octave/) that is distributed on GNU-GPL license and offers access to a subset of MATLAB's original functionality.

MATLAB questions get routinely answered in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/MATLAB). In addition to that one can check:

- [Official documentation of the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/)
- [Official MATLAB examples website](http://uk.mathworks.com/examples/statistics)
- [MATLAB Answers](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/) (A community Q&A website hosted by MathWorks)
- MIT's [Introduction to MATLAB](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-002-introduction-to-matlab-spring-2008/) course.
- Undocumented (and officially unsupported) MATLAB functionality is available in Y. Altman's [Undocumented MATLAB](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/matlab/wp-content/cache/all/index.html) website.

Answer (score 22):

## Julia

Julia is a new language with MATLAB-like syntax but Lisp-like semantics and a Lisp-style macro language.  Julia has growing capabilities for statistics, and, its main advantage, is blazing fast!   To learn about Julia, start with   https://julialang.org/
and, especially,   https://julialang.org/community/.

Julia has several online discussion groups including [julia-users](https://discourse.julialang.org/) and [julia-stats](https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/stats/12).

Answer (score 21):

## SAS

SAS questions do get asked and answered on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas); SAS also runs a [community forum](https://communities.sas.com/community/support-communities), which is very active.

The [proceedings of SUGI](http://support.sas.com/events/sasglobalforum/previous/online.html) are a tremendous resource.  Also invaluable if you need material for a corny SAS stand-up comedy routine.

The [UCLA Advanced Research Computing](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/) provides [really fantastic resources for SAS](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/).

Another resource is [SAS-L](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109114008/https://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A0=SAS-L) (site has archives and information on how to join).

The [online documentation at the SAS support page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/) is a great resource.  It includes the SAS User's Guide which contains quite detailed information on SAS procedures, including syntax, theoretical details, and examples.  As an example, [here's](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#glm_toc.htm) the page for `proc glm`.

[Lex Jansen's site](http://lexjansen.com/) indexes not only all of SAS Global Forum (formerly SUGI) but the regional meetings as well.

Comment: The link to 'various SAS blogs' via Chris Hemedinger's blog is also no longer usable.  Google reader no longer exists, so there's no way of getting to the list.

Answer (score 18):

## Stan

Stan is an open-source, probabilistic programming language implementing full Bayesian statistical inference and penalized maximum likelihood estimation.

Stan has very good [documentation](http://mc-stan.org/documentation/) (including detailed *Language Manual*), [github Wiki page](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki) and active [Stan users](http://discourse.mc-stan.org) mailing list.

Answer (score 16):

## SPSS

One forum devoted to SPSS software usage is;

- [SPSSX discussion list](http://spssx-discussion.165.s1.nabble.com/)

SPSSX receives a fairly wide variety of data manipulation questions and questions related to statistical analysis.

---

Note as all things in time change, when I initially wrote this response 12 years ago, the other forums were somewhat active. This is not the case anymore, and so I have taken them off this answer (can see the historical edits).

SPSSX is the only one that has *any* activity that is not entirely spam (the google group) or has not been decommissioned (the IBM forum). And SPSSX is pretty sparse, about one question a month in 2023 so far -- I would not bet money that listserv will be around in another 10 years.

There are still a few greybeards who answer questions on there (so it is not bad), but you may be better off at this point asking the questions about SPSS syntax on Stack overflow.

Make sure to check out the [SPSS tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/spss/info) for a more complete list of resources, many of which are freely accessible online.

Answer (score 14):

## JAGS

> JAGS is Just Another Gibbs Sampler.  It is a program for analysis of
>   Bayesian hierarchical models using Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)
>   simulation  not wholly unlike BUGS.  JAGS was written with three aims
>   in mind:
>
> - To have a cross-platform engine for the BUGS language
> - To be extensible, allowing users to write their own functions, distributions and samplers.
> - To be a plaftorm for experimentation with ideas in Bayesian modelling

(source: http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/)

Online forum for JAGS users can be found on JAGS [sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/).

Answer (score 13):

## RapidMiner

- [The one forum](https://community.rapidminer.com/)  (rapid-i developers participate, too)
- [User Manual for RM 5.x](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rapidminer/files/1.%20RapidMiner/5.1/rapidminer-5-manual-english_v1.0.pdf/)
- [Developer Manual](https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/developers/)

Answer (score 11):

## Minitab

- Tutorials for [Minitab](http://www.minitab.com/en-us/support/videos/) and [Minitab Express](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/) with examples and illustrated instructions.
- [Free assistance/support](http://www.minitab.com/en-us/support/) directly from developers (e-mail and phone call).

Learn more about Minitab on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minitab).

Answer (score 10):

## JMP

[JMP](http://jmp.com/) is a desktop statistical exploration tool from SAS.

The primary source of online support for JMP is the [JMP User Community](https://community.jmp.com/) site which hosts discussion forums and a file exchange for add-ins and data sets.

Other online resources include [JMP documentation](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/), a semi-technical [JMP blog](https://community.jmp.com/t5/Blogs/ct-p/Blogs) and weekly live [webcasts](http://www.jmp.com/about/events/webcasts/).

Comment: Too bad this isn't nested.  JMP script (JSL) is very particular and demanding.  It might qualify as its own sub-heading.

Answer (score 10):

## Fortran

Fortran is one of the main languages in which statistical algorithms have been coded.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) often has Fortran questions.

The [Open Directory](https://web.archive.org/web/20170303232835/http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Fortran/Source_Code/Statistics_and_Econometrics/) (archived) has links to many Fortran codes in statistics and econometrics.

Answer (score 9):

## Wizard

[Wizard](http://www.wizardmac.com/) is desktop statistics and data visualization package for Mac OS X. The primary support channel is the [Wizard User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wizard-users) hosted on Google Groups.

Disclosure: I am the developer of the software.

Answer (score 8):

## Weka

> Weka is a collection of machine learning algorithms for data mining tasks. The algorithms can either be applied directly to a dataset or called from your own Java code. Weka contains tools for data pre-processing, classification, regression, clustering, association rules, and visualization. It is also well-suited for developing new machine learning schemes.

A mailing list, forum, & IRC channel are listed at the Weka site under [Getting Help](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/getting_help/)

Answer (score 6):

## Taverna Workbench

It is a open source tool that has been more used for helping in data mining recently. In other words, you can create pieces of the workflow to code extracting data from different databases, analyze them, do some processing and it also supports output in R.

> ["Taverna is an open source and domain-independent Workflow Management System – a suite of tools used to design and execute scientific workflows and aid in silica experimentation"](http://www.taverna.org.uk/).

- [Taverna Website](http://www.taverna.org.uk/)
- [my Experiment - Social networking and workflow sharing environment for scientists](http://www.taverna.org.uk/introduction/taverna-features/myexperiment-integration/)
- [Curated catalogue of Web services for Life Sciences](http://www.taverna.org.uk/introduction/taverna-features/biocatalogue-integration/)
- [Mailing List](http://www.taverna.org.uk/about/contact-us/)

Answer (score 6):

## TensorFlow

[TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) is an open-source library for machine learning that was developed by Google. It has [detailed documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/) on its web site. Bugs and feature requests can be posted and viewed on TensorFlow's [github page](http://%20https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow).

Introductory tutorials on TensorFlow can be found on [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning--ud730) and [Coursera](http://deeplearning.ai/) online courses on deep learning.

Comment: On the TensorFlow discussion group, it is stated that the group is *not* for seeking help and advice. They suggest to go to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

## NONMEM

A fortran based non-linear mixed effects modelling software with very powerful algorithms including ODE solvers. It is a commercial software made by ICON plc that is widely used in the pharmacometrics community. It has a steep learning curve but once you get used to it, you'll probably not need to use another non-linear mixed effects modelling software. It needs to be used alongside other statistical tools like [R](https://www.r-project.org/) to analyse and visualise modelling results. It can also be used alongside [PsN](http://psn.sourceforge.net/) for automated covariate analysis and visual predictive checks, simulation, etc. For more on NONMEM, visit [ICON plc](https://www.iconplc.com/solutions/technologies/nonmem).

This [short tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222213234/http://accp1.org/pharmacometrics/theory.htm) (archived) gives a very concise introduction to pharmacometrics and non-linear mixed effects modelling.

Comment: Ahh.. Pharmokinetics people.. bless them. They did NLME models before it was cool.

Answer (score 5):

## ROOT

[*ROOT*](https://root.cern.ch/) is a general purpose data-analysis framework written in *C++*.  It is the *de facto* choice for any kind of analysis in the particle physics community, although it is not limited to that community.  It provides many specialised functionality through libraries, e.g.:

- `Minuit` is a minimisation library original written in `Fortran`, now reimplemented in `C++`,
- [`RooFit`](http://roofit.sourceforge.net/) is a fitting framework focused on maximum likelihood fitting,
- `RooStats` is a statistics package built around `RooFit` used to provide tools for statistical significance calculations, limit setting, etc,
- [`TMVA`](http://tmva.sourceforge.net/) is a multivariate analysis library which implements numerous machine learning algorithms like neural networks, decision trees, etc.

*ROOT* provides language bindings in other programming languages like, *Python*, *Go*, and *Ruby*.  It also provides various I/O facilites to handle very large datasets (multi-gigabyte), as well as visualisation facilities.

The package is developed as a joint effort by Fermilab and CERN.  The homepage has extensive [documentation](https://root.cern.ch/documentation) that include getting started tutorials, code examples, as well as an extensive [reference manual](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/index.html).  To get help, one can go to the [web forum](https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/) or the [mailing list](https://groups.cern.ch/group/roottalk/default.aspx).  Unfortunately to signup for the mailing list, one needs to get a lightweight CERN account (no restrictions though, anyone can get it).

Answer (score 4):

## Keras

> Keras is a high-level neural networks API, written in Python and
>   capable of running on top of TensorFlow, CNTK, or Theano. It was
>   developed with a focus on enabling fast experimentation. *Being able
>   to go from idea to result with the least possible delay is key to
>   doing good research.*

It has detailed [online documentation](https://keras.io/), users can seek help in [Keras Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/keras-users) and the [Slack channel](https://kerasteam.slack.com/). Moreover, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keras) and [Data Science Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keras) both have a tag for Keras.

Answer (score 4):

## Mplus

Mplus is a latent variable modeling program. It offers a wide range of models, estimators, and algorithms to researchers. Its analysis capabilities include a variety of basic and advanced analyses, with a special focus on analyses that include the estimation and testing of latent variables (e.g., Structural equation modeling).

For more information, visit the Mplus [website](https://www.statmodel.com/) which provides tutorials, user guides, and other sources. Additionally, [Mplus Discussion](http://www.statmodel.com/cgi-bin/discus/discus.cgi) provides a platform for users to share questions and comments about the program and modeling issues.

Answer (score 4):

## PyTorch

PyTorch comminity hosts a [list of educational resources on their page](https://pytorch.org/resources), including [Discuss forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/) and [Slack channel](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeADnUNW36fjKjYzyHDOzEB_abKQE9b6gqqW9NXse6O0MWh0A/viewform).

Answer (score 2):

## Vowpal Wabbit

VW is a command-line machine learning software that is designed to efficiently work with large amounts of data, that is not limited by RAM. It supports online learning. The software gained popularity as a tool used by multiple users on Kaggle competitions.

As described on its [github page](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit):

> Vowpal Wabbit is a machine learning system which pushes the frontier
> of machine learning with techniques such as online, hashing,
> allreduce, reductions, learning2search, active, and interactive
> learning. https://vowpalwabbit.org/

Pretty detailed documentation with code examples can be found on the [github Wiki page](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki) of the project. Video lecutres by John Langford, creator of VW, giving introductory tutorials can be found on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-x86zHUDaI) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEob9cRkpDk). There is also arXived paper ["A Reliable Effective Terascale Linear Learning System"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4198) by Agarwal et al describing theoretical basis of the software.

Answer (score 1):

## ACER ConQuest

> ACER ConQuest is a computer program for fitting both unidimensional
> and multidimensional item response and latent regression models. It
> provides data analysis based on a comprehensive and flexible range of
> item response models, allowing examination of the properties of
> performance assessments, traditional assessments and rating scales.

Support is provided via:

- [ACER ConQuest manual](https://conquestmanual.acer.org)
- [Notes and tutorials](https://www.acer.org/au/conquest/notes-tutorials)

[Download a demonstration copy](https://shop.acer.edu.au/acer-conquest-5.html)