# What should be included in tag wiki excerpt for statistical software?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just made a tag wiki for [sas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sas), and have previously made ones for [spss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spss) and [excel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel). Within these I try to provide various resources *I* think posters who ask questions related to these specific software packages would be interested in, including blogs, other forums, and books.

The excerpt for the tag-wiki (the short message that is provided when tagging a question) is sometimes used to give useful advice on how the tag should be used in our particular community. See SO's advice on [writing tag wiki excerpts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/). I believe we should **discourage** writing questions in which the only tag is one of the statistical software packages. In the context of this community, IMO this amounts to being a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Would a statement, within the tag wiki excerpt, stating this be appropriate? For an example,

> SPSS (Statistical Package for the Social Sciences) is a proprietary
>   cross-platform general-purpose statistical software package. While
>   questions related to statistical analysis in SPSS are on topic, if the
>   question is solely about programming aspects in SPSS, one is
>   encouraged to visit several of the other forums presented in the tag
>   wiki.

I'm sure this statement can be improved (I think striving for a much shorter statement is preferable), but does the community agree with the concept of putting some sort of warning message to discourage only using stat software tags for questions?

---

As an aside, I would like to encourage everyone to contribute to these (and other tag wiki's) with resources that you feel are beneficial. If you don't like the sources I have provided, think I have omitted some important ones (or think I am being too verbose) feel free to edit it. It's not like I'm the boss!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a good principle and am pleased that it is not specific to any software package.  Please note that our [FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which directly addresses this issue, and the meta thread at [Internet Support for Statistics Software](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) both constitute linkable resources that could be included in such wikis.