# Would questions about Taverna Workbench be appropriate here?

Tags: discussion

[Taverna Workbench](http://www.taverna.org.uk/) has been more and more used, and can be very well used on data mining (I am using on my current research project). However, this also seem to go under a more specific question instead of conceptual, which thus can fall under the say 'too specific to be of use for the community'. I would like to know what the community think before posting anything related to it. I am aware of their mailing list, but it is sort of dead (god knows why).

I would appreciate pointers to taverna boards or communities if you consider as a NO to questions related to this here.

Since up votes and down votes here are regarding opinion I think we can assume that for this question **a up vote means "I think Taverna workbench would be good to have on the community (maybe under a tag taverna workbench)" and down vote would mean "No I think this would not be appropriate for the community"**?

Thank you!

Comment: "Appropriated" means "assigned to" or "taken" whereas "appropriate" means "suitable for."  I think you want to lose that terminal "d"... :-)

Comment: soooorry! Not primary language. Thanks for calling my attention on that too, very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please re-read our FAQ, especially the second section beginning "There are certain subjects that will probably get better responses on our sister sites."

The principle at work here is that when a question is about concepts and the practice of *statistics* and allied fields (like machine learning, AI, data mining, etc.), it is welcome here.  When it is specifically about how to use or program a particular piece of software, it probably belongs elsewhere.  That would apply to Taverna as well as it does to R, SAS, and all the rest.

I invite you to update the [list of software-specific resources](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) we maintain on these pages.  (The list is linked from the FAQ.)

Comment: thanks that was helpful! I don't mind adding to the list, however from the example I am confused if this tool would fit there as a suggestion. Taverna is more of a tool to create workflows, so for example I can get everything automated. It does wonders as I have learned to glue your open source repositories, with a metrics tool, use resources easily, get pre-created workflows by other authors and all that. Where would this fit? Its not like it does things like R or Excel. But it is helpful on data mining. If I got the idea wrong on the question or being appropriate here please let me know :)

Comment: I see what you mean.  However, the main purpose of our software list is to help people who think of posting a question here but then realize this is not the right place: they make progress and we don't have to close an off-topic question.  If you think people may come here with Taverna questions, then having a Taverna reply on our list will help them.

Comment: great! added to the section already. Thanks for the pointer to it, didn't see the list before.