# Do we want tag warnings?

Tags: feature-request, tags

[(Stolen shamelessly from Meta.AskUbuntu.)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14237)

StackOverflow recently introduced "just in time" *tag warnings*. These warnings are meant to provide users with just-in-time information to help them avoid common mistakes in the tag they're using (e.g. SQL questions should mention the engine they use).

Here's what they look like:

[image: tag warning]

I think CV could benefit from these tag warnings, and I'll self-answer with a proposal for an [r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) tag warning.

Do y'all have other tags and warning proposals? Warnings can include links and basic HTML formatting. Please post below and upvote/downvote.

Answer (score 8):

### Proposed [r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) tag warning

> If your question is of the following type: *"How do I do X in R?"*, then CrossValidated is not
>   the best place to ask. [Here is a list of
>   support resources for this kind of
>   question.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/795/1352)
>
> CrossValidated is a good fit if your question is of this type: *"What
>   model is appropriate here? (Pointers to R packages would be
>   appreciated.)"*

Comment: +1, FWIW, I would re-order the phrases: `If your question is of the following type: "How do I do X in R?", then CrossValidated is not the best place to ask. Here is a list of support resources for this kind of question.`

Comment: @gung: thanks, that does sound better. I changed it around.

Comment: I have a concern that we may end up defining ourselves away from the current guidelines in the [on topic help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which don't quite go so far as saying this. In particular the on-topic help outlines explicit circumstances in which it might be on topic to post something like that here.